# Can´t access button value using material-ui

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I have to access the value of a button, because it holds the ID which is needed for further progress.

I first used a normal button with some bootstrap styles and everything worked fine.

```
 <button
     value={row.vacationRequestID}
     className="btn btn-warning"
     onClick={myRef.handleDeclineClick.bind(myRef)}>No
 </button>

   handleDeclineClick(e, value) {
    console.log("decline");
    console.log(e.target.value) //ID: 120
   // this.props.declineClick(e);
    //dispatch(requestStatusUpdate(e.target.value, declined, reason))
}
```

Now after using the material-ui, I can´t access the value anymore.

```
 <IconButton
    iconClassName="material-icons"
    tooltip="Ablehnen"
    value={row.vacationRequestID}
    ref={"dd"}
    onClick={myRef.handleDeclineClick.bind(myRef)}
     >
        thumb_down
    </IconButton>
```

I have tried to access it via ref, but not even this is working anymore. Can someone explain me why? The Documentation doesn´t say anything about value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MaterialUI doesn't use any `value` prop. So when you set the `value` prop to the `IconButton`, it means essentially nothing.

If you'd want to pass any value to the `onClick` call back function, bind the value to the function. So when it is called, you'll get it as the first argument.

```
myRef.handleDeclineClick.bind(myRef, row.vacationRequestID)
```

Comment: a perfect, that works! thanks I´ll accept your answer in 5 mins ;)

Answer (score 2):

Use `currentTarget` instead of `target`

```
handleDeclineClick(e, value) {
    console.log("decline");
    console.log(e.currentTarget.value);
}
```

[Original Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50414059/getting-values-from-material-ui-button-in-react#answer-50414233)