# Getting values from material-ui Button in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, formik

I have this function

```
handleChangeButton = (e) => {
    alert(e.target.value)
    this.props.setFieldValue('degreeLevel', e.target.value);
  }
```

and in my component render, I have

```
<div className="twelve columns">
            <p>Degree Level</p>
            <Button
              variant="raised"
              label="Default"
              onClick = { this.handleChangeButton }
              value="Doctorate"
            >
              Doctorate
            </Button>

            <Button variant="raised" label="Default">
              Masters
            </Button>

            <Button variant="raised" label="Default">
              Undergraduate
            </Button>
          </div>
```

So, what I want to do is, when I click the `Doctorate` button, it should `this.props.setFieldValue` to `degreeLevel` which is one of the fields in my `Formik` form. When I click the button, the alert gives me `undefined` which means it's not reading the value `Doctorate`.

How can I make `e.target.value` read the value of the button?

Comment: I guess the Button is a React component. Can you post it's code as well?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Use `currentTarget` instead of `target`

```
handleChangeButton = (e) => {
    alert(e.currentTarget.value)
    this.props.setFieldValue('degreeLevel', e.currentTarget.value);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Wondering where did you find this? I mean is this is materialUI doc? @piyush

Comment: @yugantarkumar yes it would be good to know what docs revealed this difference.

Answer (score 1):

@yugantarkumar @monsto, This is not something that is specific to Material UI, rather this is how it is done in JS by using event bubbling. You can read more about the difference here: http://www.qc4blog.com/?p=650

`currentTarget` refers to the element, to which the event listener is attached to, while `target` indicates the element that was interacted with.
In `MUI` this issue is caused by clicking on `MuiButton-label` component instead of the `MuiButtonBase` component.